# SQL Server geometry: intersection of multiple polygons

Tags: sql-server, geometry, polygon, spatial

I have multiple polygons in a table (`ImageId int, Quality float, Border geometry`).

How can I find all intersects of polygons using T-SQL functions with more high performance? Is there are any function which help to find intersections without iteration and without comparison each polygon with each Or any sample how to do it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not somewhere that I can test this right now, but if spatial aggregates work like other aggregates (i.e. string + string), let's try this:

```
declare @intersection geometry;
select top 1 @intersection = border
from #polygons;

select @intersection = border.STIntersects(@intersection)
from #polygons;

select @intersection.STIsEmpty();
```

If I've done my work correctly, @intersection should contain the intersection of all of the polygons in the table.

Comment: This query always returns isEmpty = 1 unless all of the borders have a common intersecting area! You need to compare all borders against all other borders.

Comment: @OncelUmutTURER: That's correct and is my interpretation of the OP's statement of problem. That is, given polygons A, B, C, … find A ∩ B ∩ C ∩ … .

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it apart from comparing each polygon with the others.

```
select p1.id, p2.id, p1.border.STIntersects(p2.border)
from #polygons p1
    inner join #polygons p2 on p1.id<p2.id
```

Comment: +1 - can use a cross join rather than an inner join to get all intersecting records

Answer (score 1):

By using the podiluska's code as my base code I have achieved what you are looking for. However it is not very performant. I hope someone can give a faster query.

```
select geometry::UnionAggregate(inter_geometry) as intersection_union
from
(
    select p1.id as id1, p2.id as id2, p1.border.STIntersection(p2.border) as inter_geometry
    from #polygons p1
    inner join #polygons p2 on p1.id < p2.id
    where p1.border.STIntersects(p2.border) = 1
) t
where t.inter_geometry.STArea() > 0 --for some cases STIntersects returns 1 but the area is 0
```

*by the way UnionAggregate is SQL Server 2012 function.*

Comment: To be clear, UnionAggregate does what it says on the tin. That is, given rows with spatial objects A, B, C, ... it will return A ∪ B ∪ C ∪ ... Now, if there were an IntersectionAggregate, that'd be on point and probably satisfy the OPs original problem.